# PSQL group by vs. aggregate speed

Tags: psql

So, the general question is, what's faster, taking an aggregate of a field or having extra expressions in the GROUP BY clause. Here are the two queries.

Query 1 (extra expressions in GROUP BY):

```
SELECT sum(subquery.what_i_want)
           FROM (
             SELECT table_1.some_id,
               (
                 CASE WHEN some_date_field IS NOT NULL
                   THEN
                     FLOOR(((some_date_field - current_date)::numeric / 7) + 1) * MAX(some_other_integer)
                   ELSE
                     some_integer * MAX(some_other_integer)
                 END
               ) what_i_want
             FROM table_1
             JOIN table_2 on table_1.some_id = table_2.id
             WHERE ((some_date_field IS NOT NULL AND some_date_field > current_date) OR some_integer > 0) -- per the data and what i want, one of these will always be true
             GROUP BY some_id_1, some_date_field, some_integer
           ) subquery
```

Query 2 (using an (arbitrary, because each record for the table 2 fields in question here have the same value (in this dataset)) aggregate function):

```
SELECT sum(subquery.what_i_want)
           FROM (
             SELECT table_1.some_id,
               (
                 CASE WHEN MAX(some_date_field) IS NOT NULL
                   THEN
                     FLOOR(((MAX(some_date_field) - current_date)::numeric / 7) + 1) * MAX(some_other_integer)
                   ELSE
                     MAX(some_integer) * MAX(some_other_integer)
                 END
               ) what_i_want
             FROM table_1
             JOIN table_2 on table_1.some_id = table_2.id
             WHERE ((some_date_field IS NOT NULL AND some_date_field > current_date) OR some_integer > 0) -- per the data and what i want, one of these will always be true
             GROUP BY some_id_1
           ) subquery
```

As far as I can tell, psql doesn't provide good benchmarking tools. `\timing on` only times for one query, so running a benchmark with enough trials for meaningful results is... tedious at best.

For the record, I did do this at about n=50 and saw the aggregate method (Query 2) run faster on average, but a p value of ~.13, so not quite conclusive.

'sup with that?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer - should be +- same. There's a chance to hit/miss function based index when using/not using functions on a field, but not aggregation function and in where clause more then in column list. But this is speculation only.

What you should [use for analyzing execution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) is `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. In plan you not only see scan types, but also number of iterations, cost and individual operations time. And of course you can use it with `psql`